# Fastify with AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, fastify

I trying to get working Node.JS API made on fastify running as AWS Lambda with help from `aws-lambda-fastify`.

I got to the point when I can do things inside routes, like connect to my database etc. However, when I get to `res.send()`, strange things happen.

My lambda is just the basic example the fastify lambda package.

```
const awsLambdaFastify = require('aws-lambda-fastify');
const app = require('./index');
const proxy = awsLambdaFastify(app);
exports.handler = proxy;
```

To debug what is happening, I added some console statements in one of my routes, like:

```
console.log('res.send():', res.send);
console.log('results:', filteredResults);
res.send(filteredResults);
```

In CloudWatch, I see:

```
INFO    res.send(): [Function]
INFO    results: [
{
  id: 8,
  address: 'Innsbruck Strasse',
  city: 'Park City',
  state: 'UT',
  zip: '84098',
  country: 'US',
},
...
{
  id: 9,
  address: '1000 5th Ave',
  city: 'New York',
  state: 'NY',
  zip: '10028',
  country: 'US',
}]
```

When I hit that endpoint via API Gateway, I get a 502 error. All other routes have the same problem.

I deploy using serverless. Have one route with a wildcard pointing to one lambda handler, like:

```
events:
  - http: 
      path: /{any+}
      method: ANY
      cors: true
```

I also have a resources file - `api-gateway-errors.yml`, which I maybe do not even need.

The same code [minus the aws lambda proxy] is working fine running inside Docker and physical/virtual hosts.

Comment: How do you exports the server in `'./index'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way to write the lambda, is not covered in the proxy docs. Basically, just write it as:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  proxy(event, context, callback);
}
```

This way, the callback won't wait and the lambda will not time-out. API Gateway won't then sent the 502 code.

Comment: FYI there is an option in the proxy constructor that handles `callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false`: https://github.com/fastify/aws-lambda-fastify#options